# Can python list sort key function take index instead of an element?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Take a look at this code:

```
points = [...]
properties = [compute_point_property(point) for point in points]
points.sort(?)
```

Here I have a list of points, and I compute a property of each point. Then I need to sort the points by their corresponding property value.
The problem is that the `compute_point_property` is computationally expensive, so I don't want to call it more that needed. And I also would need further to use the `properties` of the points. That means I cannot just use

```
points.sort(key=compute_point_property)
```

Because in this case the result of the `compute_point_property` is not stored in a variable for me to use further.

In my case, the elements (points) are hashable, so I can put them in dict, and use it like this:

```
points = [...]
properties = [compute_point_property(point) for point in points]
points_properties = dict(zip(points, properties))
points.sort(key=lambda point: points_properties[point])
```

It would work, but it seems wrong and unnecessarily. And it works only for hashable list elements. I want to learn how to do it with any list element type, whether it hashable or not.

Another idea is to put both point and its corresponding property into a tuple, and have a list of these tuples. Then sort the list of tuples by the second tuple element (the point property). Then extract the points from the list of tuples.

```
points = [...]
properties = [compute_point_property(point) for point in points]
points_properties = list(zip(points, properties))
points_properties.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
points = [x[0] for x in points_properties]
```

Also works, but creates a list of tuples and extracts points from the list of tuples, so it does more than actually needed.

It would be great if the `list.sort`'s key function would take an element index instead of the element value as an argument. In this case, it would be possible to do it like this:

```
points = [...]
properties = [compute_point_property(point) for point in points]
points.sort(key=lambda index: properties[index])
```

What would be the best way to sort the list while storing the computed properties?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Surely you *want* to sort `properties` with `points`? Otherwise you lose the correlation between the two lists.

Comment: @Nick, yes, that's true, but it's not a problem to sort the properties

Comment: So what's wrong with your `points_properties.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])` solution then? It does exactly what the solution you've accepted does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simpler than you think:

```
sorted_pairs = sorted((compute_point_property(point), point) for point in points)
```